# The Label's text changed without a textchanged Event handler? Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, hardcoded

i'm really new to C# and i been thinking why the label text changed when i set it in a different value without the help of a event handler?

Here's the my code :

```
class Main_Program : Form
{
    Button btnAttack = new Button();
    Label[] lblEnemyInfo = new Label[4];
    public Main_Program()
    {
        btnAttack.Text = "ATTACK";
        btnAttack.Location = new Point(350, 450);
        btnAttack.Width = 150;
        btnAttack.Height = 50;
        btnAttack.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
        btnAttack.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(btnAttack_MouseClick);

        for (short i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            lblEnemyInfo[i] = new Label();

        string enemyHealth = "Health : " + enemy.Health; //I'm going set the values on label 2
        lblEnemyInfo[1].Text = enemyHealth;
        lblEnemyInfo[1].Font = new Font("Segoi UI", 12, FontStyle.Italic);
        lblEnemyInfo[1].Location = new Point(500, 50);

        for (short i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            Controls.Add(lblEnemyInfo[i]);
    }
    private void btnAttack_MouseClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        short totalDamage = totalDamageDeal(enemy.Armor, player.Attack);
        string log = "You Attack the enemy, you deal " + totalDamage + " damage";
        enemy.Health -= totalDamage;
        string result = "Health : " + enemy.Health;
        lblEnemyInfo[1].Text = result;
        lblEnemyInfo[1].TextChanged += new EventHandler(lblEnemyInfo_TextChanged); //The label's text changed even without the eventhandler
    }
    private void lblEnemyInfo_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //i don't know what statements to put here
    }
```

}

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The `TextChanged` event is raised _when the text changes_. It's a way of notifying that the text was changed, not a way to actually change the text. There's a lot of code in your question that likely has nothing to do with what you're asking. Please provide a good [mcve] and explain what you expected to happen, and what happened instead, that you need someone to explain to you.

Answer (score 0):

An `EventHandler` is used to execute code when an event happens. If you don't want anything to happen, then don't use an event handler.

In your case, `lblEnemyInfo` is a [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx). It has a property called [Label.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d(v=vs.110).aspx) (of type string). You can change this value to update the string that the Label displays. Using `lblEnemyInfo[1].Text = "Health Down";` will make the corresponding Label display the value "Health Down" whether or not an event handler is associated with it.

You are setting an event handler for the `Label` with this code :

```
lblEnemyInfo[1].TextChanged += new EventHandler(lblEnemyInfo_TextChanged);
```

That means "whenever this `Label`'s `Text` changes, call the function named `lblEnemyInfo_TextChanged`".

There is good documentation on event handling [in this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983610(v=vs.71).aspx) (MSDN docs).